# Error code 10 when reading a characteristic in BLE - android programming

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am creating a android application to communicate to bluetooth low energy device. But In my application when I try to read a characteristic I get error status 10. does any body else have had the same problem when or why does the error status 10 occur. I could not find much about this error code.

The below is the logcat

```
04-07 14:20:34.960: D/BluetoothGatt(8360): readCharacteristic() - uuid: 0000ff0a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
04-07 14:20:34.962: D/BluetoothGatt(8360): setCharacteristicNotification() -            uuid: 0000ff0a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
04-07 14:20:34.963: I/System.out(8360): 2
04-07 14:20:34.963: I/System.out(8360): aftercalingtrue
04-07 14:20:35.033: D/BluetoothGatt(8360): onCharacteristicRead() -       Device=54:4A:16:5E:F9:69 UUID=0000ff0a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Status=10
```